# Capybara - Cucumber: Bug when two models have the same name in two different directories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, cucumber, capybara

I have 3 models:

```
# app/models/category.rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
end

# app/models/reference.rb
class Reference < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category, class_name: "Category::Reference"
end

# app/models/category/reference.rb
class Category::Reference < ::Category
  has_many :references
end
```

As you can see two models have the same name but not the same goal.

In my controller when I do:

```
def new
  @category = Category::Reference.new
  raise @category.inspect
end
```

it raises in my rails server:

`#<Category::Reference id: nil, title: nil, position: nil, slug: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>`

But the same raise when I do a `visit` with capybara raises:

`#<Reference id: nil, title: nil, position: nil, description: nil,  created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>`

As you can see rails raises the good instance `Category::Reference` whereas capybara raises the wrong one `Reference`

I think I will need to rename my inherited model but it's a pity!

Thanks

(I have already opened an issue on [github](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/1210) without answer for the moment)
Config:

- Ruby 2.0
- Rails 4.0.2
- Capybara 2.2.0

**EDIT:**

It seems it's not due to the class name but to the directory name. If I change :

```
# app/models/category/reference.rb
class Category::Reference < ::Category
  has_many :references
end
```

by

```
# app/models/categories/reference.rb
class Categories::Reference < ::Category
  has_many :references
end
```

It works well...

Comment: try `@category = ::Category::Reference.new`

Comment: I didn't mentionned that but I already try it. And it doesn't work.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you can't simply use `class Reference < Category`?